# what type of log in should i use?

Tags: android

I was wondering, i have an android app that a user fills in details which upload to a database then to a website i would like each users posts to be tracked by email

I would like the user to login and am unsure of what to use, my choice is between Open ID and facebook connect - it doesnt worry me that not all users will have facebook.

Would anyone have any advice at which is better or any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is an Open ID provider, and all android users have a Google account. Based on that I'd say Open ID is your best shot.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials?